# Change GridView row color based on condition in DataBinder Eval

Tags: c#, gridview, row, background-color

I want to change a particular row color of GridView based on some condition.

I am using ASP.NET with c#.

I have tried without success this code-behind:

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, 
   "myHour")).ToString("HH:mm:ss") >= "00:00:00")
{
    e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

I have error:

> Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and
>   'string'

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "myHour")) 
    >= Convert.ToDateTime("00:00:00")
{
    e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```